# JFrame not appearing in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have written a simple java application that squares and roots a number depending on the clicked button. Once I run it, the console displays that the build was successful but nothing is shown. Here's my code:

```
package lab11;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Problem1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

int n;
JTextField enter;
JTextField result;
JButton sqrt;
JButton square;
JLabel l1;
JLabel l2;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Problem1 exercice = new Problem1();
    exercice.setSize(500, 500);
    exercice.setVisible(true);
    exercice.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    exercice.show(true);
}

public Problem1(){

    super("Square Root");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    l1 = new JLabel("Enter N:");
    l2 = new JLabel("Result:");
    sqrt = new JButton("SQRT");
    square = new JButton("SQUARE");
    square.addActionListener(this);
    sqrt.addActionListener(this);
    n = Integer.parseInt(enter.getText());
    add(l1);
    add(enter);
    add(l2);
    add(result);
    add(sqrt);
    add(square);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == square)
        result.setText(String.valueOf(n*n));
    if(e.getSource()== sqrt)
        result.setText(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(n)));

}

}
```

Comment: I "suspect" you have an exception at `n = Integer.parseInt(enter.getText());` as `enter` is `null` (and if it wasn't `getText()` would return a blank `String` which can't be converted to `int`)

Comment: `JTextField enter` should probably be `JSpinner enter`..

Comment: @MadProgrammer correct, once I set my project to main class, n was null pointer exception-ed . I added the condition that n is only parsed when enter.getText() is not null but that didn't seem to fix the problem. my main method "problem 1 exercice = new problem();" also suffered from the same problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the exercise limits us only to JTextField because the value must be entered by the user, not chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set the JFrame as your project's main class, in the tab 'Project' in the name of the project(coffee cup icon), right click -> set configuration -> customize -> in the section 'Run' click on the Browse button to select the default Main Class (your desired JFrame).

Comment: thanks! Netbeans was running the default class instead of this one. But problems persist with null pointer exceptions when parsing to the n integer and when calling the class in the main.

Answer (score 0):

`right click` -> `set configuration` -> `customize` -> in the section `Run` and select your project.